# How to solve Python allocate stack error: 'freesize < size'?

Tags: python

While trying to build my dockerfile, I am getting the below error:

`` python3: allocatestack.c:194: advise_stack_range: Assertion `freesize < size' failed. ``

The command at which my dockerfile is failing is when i run:

```
STEP 4: RUN dnf -y install     --setopt=deltarpm=0     --setopt=install_weak_deps=false     --setopt=tsflags=nodocs     httpd     gcc     libffi-devel     libpq-devel     mod_auth_gssapi     mod_ssl     mod_wsgi     krb5-devel     python3-pip     python3-setuptools     python-devel     redhat-rpm-config     && dnf clean all
```

I tried to look up for this error but I couldn't find it.
Could someone help me understand what this error message means?

Also what are the possible solutions?

Comment: It means you're out of RAM.